# Optimize API in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I want to call a stored procedure in Oracle using `SimpleJdbcCall`, and then return the result, and map it to my Java class. Later, I try to find out why my API is so slow. I try to execute the query in Oracle, it runs fast. So I think the problem is in my code.

I use either one of this data sources:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {    
    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
            .url(url)
            .username(username)
            .password(password);
    return factory.build();
}
```

I tested both connections via Postman only, why using `DataSourceBuilder` is faster than `OracleDataSource`?

This is my first time to optimize an API. I don't know if this is wrong or right.

Comment: My first guess, `OracleDataSource` is not a connection pool, and what is returned by `DataSourceBuilder` is.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah, i think so. yesterday, i finally changed my connection pool to HikariCP. that works. :)

Comment: You can also use Universal Connection Pool (UCP), Refer to SpringBootApp (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/SpringBootApp) for more details.